# Can't let a user post in the chat room even though the description for granting explicit writing access says it should work

Tags: support, chat

[image]

The room is public, and the user is a dedicated chat bot account to avoid receiving spam notifications on my main account. I don't want to ask questions and receive upvotes on that bot account, as that's frowned upon and I've seen people get in trouble like that. The description says clear as day that this should work, but then the red error text says nu-uh. Wat do?

Answer (score 3):

This is meant for Gallery chat rooms, where users can't post unless given that explicit write access.

Only moderators can give users with less than 20 reputation the ability to post in a chat room.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll ask a friendly mod then. But the description should be changed to clarify this condition.

Comment: @user1306322 Well, the message is for both ordinary users and moderators, so maybe adding (moderator only) after the "reputation too low" would indeed clear this confusion.

Comment: @user1306322 I'm sure https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room can't be far off now... Just another 6-8...